# Apparantly successful virt-install of Clear Linux cannot boot

Tags: kvm-virtualization, installation, boot

First, I create a clear linux vm with virt-install

```
virt-install \
--name CLEAR \
--ram 65536 \
--disk path=/guest_images/Linux_main/CLEAR.img,bus=virtio,size=450 \
--vcpus 8 \
--os-type linux \
--os-variant generic \
--network bridge=virbr0 \
--graphics vnc  \
--console pty,target_type=serial \
--cdrom /media/big-tank-8TB/OSISOS/clear-25720-installer.iso
```

The installer starts up and I choose the only available device "vda", which I assume must be the CLEAR.img file, so I choose to create a parition there and install (also, not sure why no partitions show, this img is on a zvol that I had previously formatted to ext4)
[image]

The installer apparently completes successfully.

[image]

But after rebooting, I am stuck in Seabios "booting from the hard disk"

[image]

I tried changing the drive interface from virtio to ide, but it did not help. Not sure what to try next.

I also tried [these instructions from the Clear Linux website](https://clearlinux.org/documentation/clear-linux/get-started/virtual-machine-install/kvm) with which I was able to start up, but ran into problems connecting via vnc, and more relevant to my question, when I tried to virt-install start the provided .img file, I got the same seabios "booting from hard disk" forever that I got after installing via the .iso. I suspect the problem might be that I need to provide a UEFI file like in the Clear Linux instructions, but I am not sure how to do this when using virsh and and existing VM.

Comment: Um, why do you call CLEAR.img a file, and then call it a zvol in the next sentence? What is it really?

Comment: CLEAR.img is a file, located on a zvol. I used this same approach to create other VMs, so whatever is going on here is specific to Clear Linux.

Comment: OK, now I get it. That's perhaps one more level of indirection than I'd prefer; I just use the zvol directly as the VM's disk.

Comment: Wait, how do you do that? I thought the way to do it was to make the zvol, and then create the KVM img on that zvol? Is there a way to put a virtual machine onto the disk without creating a .img file?

Comment: Sure, use `/dev/zvol/tank/clear` or whatever as the raw disk image.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip, I had completely misunderstood how that worked. Unfortunately, I still have the same problem. I will next try using these instructions on the Clear Linux website, although I am unclear if I can move it from the .img provided to a raw zvol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is indeed that you need to provide the UEFI firmware.

You will need to add the `--boot uefi` option.

Reference: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Using_UEFI_with_QEMU#virt-install

You may also need to update the OVMF firmware on your system. Clear Linux provides an up to date one at https://download.clearlinux.org/image/. They also provide the `_CODE` and `_VARS` fd's might need to be updated in the nvram section of your

`/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf`

```
    #nvram = [
    #   "/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd:/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS.fd",
    #   "/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.secboot.fd:/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS.fd",
    #   "/usr/share/AAVMF/AAVMF_CODE.fd:/usr/share/AAVMF/AAVMF_VARS.fd",
    #   "/usr/share/AAVMF/AAVMF32_CODE.fd:/usr/share/AAVMF/AAVMF32_VARS.fd"
    #]
```

This also might be helpful: https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/commit/d2fffa509efe891eef3f2f70e5688c1d6e3a2d87

You might be fine just passing that flag. Otherwise I'd try the `nvram` section. Personally I use their `start_qemu.sh` script. But I wish you luck.